# Starting linux kernel threads without wake_up_process

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling

I want to start several Linux kernel threads using `kthread_create` (not the `kthread_run`), but in my driver there are some probability that some of threads will be not woken up with `wake_up_process`.

Is it correct to create all threads with `kthread_create` and not wake they up?
I think, some threads may get stuck in TASK_UNINTERRUPTABLE.

The problem is that I can't wake up the thread before the data for thread will be ready. If I do, then thread will try to parse unavailable data. And sometimes there will be data not for all threads.

Also, I can't start the thread at time when data will be available because this is too long to start the thread for my requirements.

Comment: How about threads waiting on a condition(or lock) that is set true when data is ready to be processed ? So they are ready and running, just waiting for trigger.

Comment: spa, yes, if I will rewrite code. The quesion is - how correct is the current variant - without wake up for some processes?